# How to record audio on a smartphone from a mixer

Tags: audio, lg, headphones

I understand this may be the wrong forum, but I don't know where else to ask.

I have an LG V30, USB C to 3.5mm headphone jack adapter, and an aux cord(male to male). What I am trying to do is record audio on my phone, from a digital mixer at my church. This is all the hardware I have for now, but I could by more if I need to. My goal is to record audio from the mixer to my phone. I am wondering if I can connect one end of the aux cord into the mixer headphone jack for output, and the other end either into the headphone jack on my phone, or the charging port using the adapter. I think I will use the default audio recording app on the V30. Is this gonna work? If not, what apps/hardware do I have to purchase to make this work, and how would I have to hook it up.

Please note that I am do not record audio, and I would need a very clear explanation

Comment: Whether the "adapter" you have will work depends on whether your phone includes drivers for USB audio devices. The easiest way to find out will be to try it.